# When sculpting, it isn't mirroring

Tags: sculpting

So I have a basic mesh of my creature, and I want to sculpt the finer details. So I set the sculpt tool to mirror across the x-axis (Yes, I double checked that this is the right axis, but it isn't mirroring. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does "double checked that this is the right axis" mean? How did you check? Did you check if rotation is applied? (Object mode>Ctrl+A). If "it isn't mirroring" then what does it do? [Edit] your question with more details

Comment: @MrZak I meant I checked that the x-axis was the one going through the center of my object in the direction I wanted it to

Comment: So is the rotation applied or not? Global axis isn't always the same as local for object.

Comment: @MrZak The axis isn't the problem, it doesn't mirror on any axis

Comment: For symmetric sculpting to work, the mesh topology must be identical, if you have made a change to one side it will break the mirroring. In the dyntopo panel, there is an option to symmetrise the mesh to fix this so you can start using mirroring.

Comment: As above, include more details, particularly screenshots of the mesh. Probably your mesh indeed is not symmetrical due to some changes on that axis only, probably something with object's rotation. Guessing is always slow.